# Extract only day and month with lubridate in R and conserve the date format

Tags: r, date, dplyr, format, lubridate

I would like to achieve this without loosing the *date* format

```
ID    Date         DayMonth
1     2004-02-06   06-02
2     2006-03-14   14-03
3     2007-07-16   16-07
...   ...          ...
```

Thanks

This is one way to do it but is there a faster way and keeping the date format (as.date)

```
date = df %>% mutate(DayDate=day(Date)) %>% mutate(MonthDate=month(Date)) %>%
  unite(DayMonth, c("DayDate", "MonthDate"), sep = "-")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of the `unite` step after creating two columns, we can do this directly with `format`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(DayMonth = format(as.Date(Date), "%d-%m"))
#  ID       Date DayMonth
#1  1 2004-02-06    06-02
#2  2 2006-03-14    14-03
#3  3 2007-07-16    16-07
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df$DayMonth <- format(as.Date(df$Date), "%d-%m")
```

#### Benchmarks

On a slightly bigger dataset

```
library(tidyr)
library(lubridate)
df1 <- df %>% 
          uncount(1e6)
df1$Date <- as.Date(df1$Date)
system.time({df1 %>%
               mutate(DayDate=day(Date)) %>%
               mutate(MonthDate=month(Date)) %>%
               unite(DayMonth, c("DayDate", "MonthDate"), sep = "-")
                })
# user  system elapsed 
#  1.998   0.030   2.014 

system.time({df1 %>%
                mutate(DayMonth = format(Date, "%d-%m"))})
#   user  system elapsed 
#  1.119   0.001   1.118
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, Date = c("2004-02-06", "2006-03-14", 
"2007-07-16")), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I don't know who voted, but what I see is that the OP asked a performance question and the above first response did not show speed comparisons.  A solution might be to run a)OP mutate, b)dplyr format, c)baseR, d)paste, etc and get some timing

Answer (score 1):

other alternative is:

```
date <-  df %>% as.Date(paste0(as.character(day(Date)), '-',as.character(month(Date))), format='%d-%m')
```